# How to solve twig and yaml loaders with webpack

Tags: webpack, drupal, yaml, twig

I'm working with a drupal project using webpack and twig components,
When I'm trying to build the project using `yarn watch`,
A huge number of errors happening for twig and yaml extensions, like the following screeshot: [image: error]

Comment: I think must be some yarn or theming (JSON) gulp, npm or whatever config issue, which also targeting or trying to parse the twig files from theme. But yarn should touch only `scss` `css` or `js` files.
Twig is only used for templating purpose, to be parsed by Drupal only

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states it needs a loader for twig files.
Maybe [twing-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twing-loader) would help.